# Which is better millis() or timer?

Tags: esp8266, millis

I want to create a 30 minutes delay in my program (Arduino).

which is better `millis()` or timer for this purpose?

please give me an example to clarify my doubt ...

Thanks.

Comment: sleep is best for 30 minutes

Comment: the same question with more info https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=627149.0

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your need:

**1. No other activities / main power**

If during those 30 minutes (I guess), the MCU does not have to do anything else (except maybe handling some short interrupts), than you can use a delay. You can use this if your power source is an adapter, but you waste a lot.

- Advantage: Easy to program
- Disadvantage: Power will continue to be used.

**2. No other activities / battery**

If you have the same conditions as above, but using a battery, than as Juraj mention, use the sleep functionality of the Arduino. You need an (external) real time clock or other circuitry to activate the wakeup signal after 30 minutes.

- Advantage: Very less power used during the 30 minute delay
- Disadvantage: Slightly more programming

**3. Other activities**

If you want to do now (or later) other code to be executed during the 30 minute wait, use `millis()`. For example, when you want to extend your project using other libraries that needs a faster than 30 minute response.

- Advantage: You can do other tasks meanwhile
- Disadvantage: More power usage, slightly more programming

Comment: 2) esp8266 has built-in RTC with deep sleep wake-up option

Comment: 3) for example blink a LED to show that it is alive

Comment: 1) interrupts to keep the WiFi connected

Comment: @Juraj thanks for the extra comments .. offtopic:. btw congratulations with your 10K reputation. I removed my other answer so you don't need to downvote it anymore).